# How can I get Database name, Size, Table name, Objects, Indexes, Check Constraints, Foreign keys in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a query to get all the details as mentioned in Subject. I am sure there should be one developed with the same requirement.

Comment: The answer depends on your database engine, which you didn't provide.

Comment: What database do you mean? This thing is different in different databases?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have an Oracle database with 50 tables. I need a resultset with columns as mentioned in the subject. hope that clarifies the query

Comment: Yes, now it is clear. But one thing. Does your user(schema) has SELECT_ANY_DICTIONARY privilege? Or are you able to SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS for example?

Comment: I mean, do you want the single query for current schema or any schema?

Comment: Additionally, you did not describe a form of the result. It is possible to make plain table or hirerchical result (using CONNECT BY clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
select user schema,'1.FIELDS' obj, null name, c.TABLE_NAME,c.COLUMN_ID col_order,c.COLUMN_NAME,
c.DATA_TYPE,c.DATA_LENGTH,c.DATA_PRECISION,c.DATA_SCALE,c.NULLABLE,null condition
from user_tab_columns c
union all
select user,'2.INDEX '||uniqueness,index_name,table_name,i.column_position, i.column_name,null,
null,null,null,null,null
from user_ind_columns i inner join user_indexes using(table_name,index_name)
union all
select user,'3.CONSTR', constraint_name, table_name, csc.position, csc.column_name,null,null,
null,null,null,cs.search_condition
from user_constraints cs inner join user_cons_columns csc using (table_name,constraint_name)
where constraint_type='C'
union all
select user,'4.FK', constraint_name, table_name, csc.position, csc.column_name||'->'||r_constraint_name,
null,null,null,null,null,cs.search_condition
from user_constraints cs inner join user_cons_columns csc using (table_name,constraint_name)
where constraint_type='R'
order by  4, 2, 3, 5
```

This will show information regarding to all tables in the curren schema. For each table it shows 1) fields 2) indexes 3) constraints 4) foreign keys